# How to get value in a textbox that is readonly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox.In its onclick iam calling a javascript fn to call calendar.Texbox is readonly. Clicking on textbox calendar is coming and value is showing in textbox. But on clicking submit button where I have written code to save, there i am not getting value in textbox. What may be the reason for that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that your text box has the [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) attribute instead of [readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.2) which prevents it from posting its value to the server.

Comment: darin, is readonly supported by all the common browsers? Didn't know about this attribute.

Comment: This does not work, although what does is the suggestion below where you don't set the readonly properties in designer mode but in the codebehind on page load.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too, there is a really simple workaround

Instead of making the textbox ReadOnly using properties option. Do it thru the code behind adding this code:

```
YourTextBox.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value by using

```
Request.Form[YourTextBox.UniqueID]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the textbox is disabled so that people have to use the calendar control to enter a date? The textbox is just for showing the selected date?

If you want the textbox to stay readonly (i.e. disabled client-side), have a hidden input that has the value you want to handle on the server is the way to go probably. So add an additional input for to the page. Use

```
<asp:HiddenField ... runat="server" />
```

So the client-side code that updates your readonly textbox will also update your hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

if readonly property is true, its not break your .cs call. you can use this as always:

here are your inputs:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBraid" runat="server" Text="Im sooo readonly" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblBraid" runat="server" Text="Im gonna change, i promise"></asp:Label>
```

on .cs page put these to onClick function or something:

```
lblBraid.Text = txtBraid.Text;
```